# In what occasions can we get a NullPointerException("Name is null"); error?

Tags: nullpointerexception, java

Besides, the `valueOf()` method of Java's `Enum` class API, does anyone know, if any other Java API class throws that same exception, i.e., `NullPointerException("Name is null");`?

Comment: I don't uderstand the downvotes. I thing the OP wants to know if there are any other methods that throw NPE with specified message("Name is null"). The message is not constant for all NPE occurances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RickS how is it duplicate? There is no answer which method throws NPE with that message.
Default NPE message is `null`. For enums it is `Name is null` if you do `valueOf(null)`;

Comment: @MichałSchielmann Instead of commenting and downvoting everyone, why don't you answer the question.  You seem to be the NullPointer police here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a list of things.

Comment: @RickS why the emotions? I just think the question is valid (not duplicate for sure). It's strage, not clear. Why someone would need that - I have no idea. But that's not the reason for downvoting/flagging as duplicate. I would rather go for off-topic as Henry suggested.
If I knew the answer I would have answered it. And what is wrong with downvoting wrong answers? Thats what the votes are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no others:

```
$ pwd
/c/apps/java/jdk1.8.0/src

$ grep -r "\"Name is null"\" *
java/lang/Enum.java:            throw new NullPointerException("Name is null");
```

There are, of course, many **other** Java APIs (not the Oracle Java SDK) that could  throw exactly the same exception...